# In C/WebAssembly how do I post a message out of a Worker and catch it in the main JavaScript thread?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to "run before I can walk" with WebAssembly using C and Emscripten.

I have a monolithic single-threaded "vanilla C" console application that I want to host as a Web App using xterm.js to supply its stdio.

So far I've worked out that the WASM needs to be run inside a Web Worker (because `main()` doesn't exit except as the result of an explicit "quit" action by the user) and I might have cobbled that together, but as far as I can tell the worker doesn't have access to the global `Module` object and in particular it's `print()` function - *for the moment I'll be happy to get output working, I know that input is a different kettle of fish*.

From what I can understand instead of relying on C stdout being redirected to `print()` I need to replace stdout calls with code to post messages from the worker (C code) that I can then catch and handle/render in the main JavaScript thread. Assuming I am not barking up the wrong tree, can someone give me some pointers/snippets of code showing how this can be done ?

Best wishes,

Tom

Comment: This depends on how you compiled it - as standalone wasm file or with emscripten's stdlib env? The latter is easier to get something rolling, but might need manual work to get things through to your main context (you might have to intercept/edit the console syscalls there). Prolly easier is to import your own write function as `write(char *s, int num)`, grab data in JS from wasm memory (pointer+num), then do the postMessage thingy to main.